# Python calculate a new column based on conditions and values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'd like to calculate transaction returns in a new column based on some conditions. My data frame looks like this:

```
stock   price  date            year    yearend price  buy/sell  transaction-volume  aggrvolumne
A        10    2020-2-1        2020       15            buy          100                 100
A        12    2020-12-1       2020       15            sell         50                   50
A        18    2021-2-1        2021       20            sell         50                   0
B
B
```

I need to group the data frame by stocks.
and for the third transaction, I need to look for the last "buy" transaction to get its cost.

The outcome should be like this:

```
stock   price  date            year    yearend price  buy/sell  transaction-volume  aggrvolumne   return 
A        10    2020-2-1        2020       15            buy          100                 100     NaN
A        12    2020-12-1       2020       15            sell         50                   50     20%
A        18    2021-2-1        2021       20            sell         50                   0     80%
B
B
```

So how to locate the last 'buy' row in the same group, and get the price I need?

Comment: What if the `sell` happens before `buy` or if there are two or more consecutive `buy's` before `sell`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I filtered the transactions, so for every stock, the transactions start from buy. If several buys before selling, then the first in first out applies-- use the first buy price until the volume of the first buy is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment , if every first transaction for a given stock is a buy, you could identify and retrieve its price with this:

```
df.groupby('stock')['price'].transform('first')
```

Then , we could take its return based on that value

```
df['return']=(df.groupby('stock')['price'].transform(pd.Series)-df.groupby('stock')['price'].transform('first'))/(df.groupby('stock')['price'].transform('first'))*100
```